# Client defined categories

Tags: categories

I'm building an event schedule and I'm trying to conceptually figure out how to relate speaker information (name, title, bio) to times lots that the client will define.

Example:

**9-10am Session I**
 - Link to Speaker 1
 - Link to Speaker 2
 - Link to Speaker 3

I've done this type of relation with other channels simply through using categories, but in this case I do not know what the time slots will be to set up the categories and template code in advance.

Is the solution as simple as giving the client access to the category group and have them add custom categories that correspond with the time slot?

Sorry if my questions are very basic. This is my first EE site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the timeslots then it makes any solution a bit trickier. You could do it via categories by setting up a [category group](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/category_create_group.html) and then opening up access to your clients to add their timeslot as a category and tick that. It's probably not the cleanest solution however.

You may find [Low Events](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-events) to be useful in this situation which provides a specialised fieldtype for the purpose and makes it easier to retrieve information in your templates later on as needed.

This type of scenario is also more of a relationship where you would relate ***Speakers*** to an ***Event*** and allocate a timeslot. EE 2.6 (released earlier this week) now provides a big improvement to native relationship handling which, again could be useful addition in this scenario. If used in combination with [Matrix](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix) then you could allow the users to log in and add themselves to a single Event entry with speakers, timeslots and topics in a grid display.

It all depends on your particular use case. But that should provide a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you'd want separate channels for events and speakers and then use EE's native [relationship](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html) field or [Playa](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa/) to relate speakers to events.

Comment: I agree - that's the way I've done it as well, particularly since with some kinds of events, you could have the same speaker appear more than once and so using playa for a relationship with events is a flexible way to avoid all that content being contained in each time slot's entry, resulting in potential duplication.  Each event would contain the time slot and details of the event, and a relationship field for the assignment of speakers from the speakers channel.  It gives you some great flexibility have additional displays - like display a list of speakers with times at which they speak.